# USB Ports Inoperative After Windows 10 Reset, Works in BIOS

Tags: windows-10, usb, reset

I purchased a used computer (Dell Optiplex 780) with Windows 10 preinstalled (Product Key sticker says Windows 7, must have been upgraded). At startup everything worked fine but a user account is already present, I would like to start from scratch so the first thing I do is "Reset this PC" and "Remove everything".

When the system boots I can press F12 for Boot Options and do anything I want in there. However, whenever I get as far as Windows loading up, the keyboard and mouse no longer work. I cannot begin the initial setup process.

In the Boot Device Menu I ran the full Diagnostics test to no avail. In System Setup I've clicked "Load Defaults" which didn't work. I also checked System Configuration > USB Controller, which is Enabled. Lastly, Front USB and Rear Dual USB are both enabled in Miscellaneous Devices.

This is a small form factor machine with no PS/2 port on the back to try to bypass the USB. I have no idea how to get this machine to recognize my USB keyboard and mouse.

Comment: The Reset image seems to lack some drivers. It might go better to reinstall Windows 10 version 1903 (or 1909) from a boot media, as this will most likely be more recent.

Comment: See if there's a *legacy USB* option in the BIOS - might work for the setup process.

Comment: harrymc Thank you! I used a different Windows 10 image to install the OS and everything went swimmingly from there. I hope I can give you proper approval for your answer through comments.